# How can I draw double sided intersecting arrows?

Tags: graphics, tikz-arrows

I was wondering how to draw double sided intersecting arrows like the ones shown in my drawing. Any help would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Is this specific to Ti*k*z? Or just arrows in general that intersect (for use in math, say)?

Answer (score 2):

#### New answer

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
doublesided/.pic={
\draw[<->](-.4,0)--(.4,0);
\draw[<->](0,.4)--(0,-.4);
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\draw (0,0)grid(5,3);
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,2}{\pic at (\i+.5,\j+.5){doublesided};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

Like this?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[<->](-.5,0)--(.5,0);
\draw[<->](0,.5)--(0,-.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that is great, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how I would add this to every box in a grid?

Comment: Or should I start a new thread

Comment: Another possibility that is easy to add more arrows: `\begin{tikzpicture}\foreach \a in {0,90,180,270}\draw[->](0,0)--(\a:.5cm);\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @KaneM I've updated my answer, is that what you want?